# What's the difference between BufferUtils and MemoryUtil? (LWJGL)

Tags: java, memory, buffer, lwjgl

I always used `MemoryUtil` to store float buffers, but people seem to use `BufferUtils` for it:

```java
private IntBuffer convertToIntBuffer(int[] data) {
    IntBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(data.length);        
    return buffer.put(data).flip();
}
```

```java
private FloatBuffer convertToFloatBuffer(float[] data) {
    FloatBuffer buffer = MemoryUtil.memAllocFloat(data.length);     
    return buffer.put(data).flip();
}
```

Comment: There are no such classes in Java SE itself, so please specify the fully-qualified names of these classes, and add relevant tags for the specific library (libraries) to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LWJGL 3's `org.lwjgl.BufferUtils` class is only a small facade over Java's `java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocateDirect()` method, allowing you to use the JVM's memory allocator to allocate off-heap memory and return a NIO `ByteBuffer` (or typed view thereof), including making sure that the ByteOrder is `nativeOrder()`.

The NIO Buffer allocated by `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect()` is managed by the JRE internally and the native memory is freed implicitly as part of the garbage collection cycle once it becomes unreachable.

There are a lot of downsides to allocating off-heap memory with this approach, such as (quote from "[Memory management in LWJGL 3](https://blog.lwjgl.org/memory-management-in-lwjgl-3/)"):

-begin-of-quote-

- It is slow, much slower than the raw malloc() call. A lot of overhead on top of a function that is already slow.
- It scales badly under contention.
- It arbitrarily limits the amount of allocated memory (-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize).
- Like Java arrays, the allocated memory is always zeroed-out. This is not necessarily bad, but having the option would be better.
- There's no way to deallocate the allocated memory on demand (without JDK-specific reflection hacks). Instead, a reference queue is used that usually requires two GC cycles to free the native memory. This quite often leads to OOM errors under pressure.

-end of quote-

LWJGL 3's `org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil` class on the other hand allows you to use other native/off-heap memory allocators instead of the JVM's ByteBuffer allocator to allocate off-heap native memory, including the option of just giving you the raw virtual memory address as a `long`, avoiding the NIO `Buffer` instance.

LWJGL supports the system allocator of the C standard library (malloc) as well as currently [jemalloc](https://github.com/jemalloc/jemalloc) and [rpmalloc](https://github.com/mjansson/rpmalloc). All of these provide a very much faster alternative to Java's ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(), alleviating the above mentioned drawbacks.

Because the native memory is *not* managed by the JVM anymore, you *have to* free the memory yourself, for which there is the `org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.memFree()` method.

Before you continue, you should however read the mentioned LWJGL blog post in its entirety, as there are more options, such as `org.lwjgl.system.MemoryStack`, for allocating native off-heap memory in particular situations (such as short-lived memory), which is even faster than all the other alternatives above mentioned.

Comment: so, i shall use memUtil for alocating memory, but manage memory by myself